# Starting ios webkit debug proxy through program

Tags: java, ios, iphone, appium

I am working on creating test environment for iPhone automation[real device] and want to eliminate as much manual effort as possible.

Is it possible to launch and terminate ios_webkit_debug_proxy using Java.